# How can I deprecate external libraries in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm am looking to deprecate usage of a specific dependency inside of my project.

- Scala / sbt has any mechanism to do it?

Comment: Something like giving warnings if you use a specific library?

Comment: You can try this sbt-plugin: https://github.com/hmrc/sbt-bobby (this plugin can be configured in order to give error on some pre defined dependencies)

Comment: Yes, something like a warning is a good idea.